# How to access data from file in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am kind of stuck at the moment. I am trying to load data into one of my components and pass it to another component. However I am not able to access the data. I receive the following error:

**TypeError: data.map is not a function**

I believe that I am not accessing the imported data (import data from '../src/data/data') correctly when saving it into my **const data**

This is what my component List.js looks like at the moment:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Article from './Article'
require ('../src/sass/List.scss');
import data from '../src/data/data'

class List extends Component {

  render() {

    const data = {data}
    const listWebsites = data.map(websites => {

        return (
            <Article key={websites.id} name={websites.name} preview={websites.description} image={websites.image} />
            )
    })

    console.log('our data is:', this.props.data)
    return (
      <div className="wrapperList">
          {listWebsites}

        </div>
    )
  }

}

export default List
```

This is my data file:

```
const data = [
  {
    'id': '1',
    'name': 'Skyscanner',
    'description': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr ',
    'image': 'skyscanner.png',

  },
  {
    'id': '2',
    'name': 'Momondo',
    'description': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr  ',
    'image': 'monondo.jpg',

  },
  {
    'id': '3',
    'name': 'Skypicker',
    'description': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr ',
    'image': 'Skypicker.jpg',

  },
  {
    'id': '4',
    'name': 'Atob',
    'description': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr  ',
    'image': 'Atob.jpg',

  },
   {
    'id': '5',
    'name': 'flipper',
    'description': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr ',
    'image': 'flipper.jpg',

  },

];

export default data;
```

Could you please help me to fix this and tell me how to access the data correctly? Thanks a lot

Comment: You definitely don't want to do `const data = {data}` here. Can you show us '../src/data/data'? Also, why don't you pass that information as props?

Comment: Well I passed the data first through my App.js into this compent however I wanted to changes this because of a routing related problem and access the data right away in List.js. I also added my data file.

Comment: Maybe you should solve that "routing related problem", or you'll get into other issues when that data becomes mutable. So far the error points to `const data = {data}`. Don't do this and that problem should vanish.

Comment: thanks that actually helped me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting your data as default which in this case is basically the same as

```
export default [
  {
    'id': '1',
    'name': 'Skyscanner',
    'description': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr ',
    'image': 'skyscanner.png',

  }, ....
];
```

Because of this, you can import normally without worrying about what you set your variable name to.

```
import data from '../src/data'
```